# Appengine has no instances deployed

Tags: google-app-engine

Anyone ever experienced a google managed appengine instance disappearing ?

Everything is fine and suddenly every query starts going 500. The admin said `This app has no instances deployed.` with logs saying `Request attempted to contact a stopped backend.`.

It happens every week at a random time and It can last 30~45 min.
Last time it happened a deployment was done 2 days ago.
That's scary.
yaml looks like this :

```
module: default
runtime: go
api_version: go1
vm: true

#automatic_scaling's default settings as nothing is set

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Can we avoid this ? Is it our fault ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like expected behavior. I would suggest to log a bug to AppEngine https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3, add with as much details as possible.